# How do we create NFC Passes which can be added in to Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

I am trying to create NFC Pass which i need to add into Apple Wallet.

I have tried creating pass using passkit but that is not NFC Pass what is there specifically used for NFC Passes apart from NFC pass certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the pass using an NFC certificate and also have the nfc field in the pass.json with nested message and encryptionPublicKey.

Once you have this, reading and decrypting the nfc message uses the certificate to read the data securely.

You need to get access to documentation from Apple on how to do this as it is under NDA.

At passninja, we will be providing developers with the ability to use our certs, apis and readers to manage the entire lifecycle of creating, reading and decrypting Apple Pay and Google Pay passes.

Comment: Thanks ! for the information Scott. Could you help in getting dummy JSON format for NFC Passes. i.e. what kind of nfc field needs to be added ?